# Difference in numpy np.zeros((1,2)) vs np.zeros((2,))

Tags: python, numpy

I am stuck in this question. Can anybody explain me the difference between these two?

```
np.zeros ((1,2))
```

which yields

```
[[0. 0.]]
```

and

```
np.zeros((2,))
```

which yields

```
[0. 0.]
```

Comment: Even a 'beginner' can count the brackets!

Comment: Really? You didnt seem to understand the question dude. I am asking what difference does that make? I can count the bracket.

Comment: Would you have problems with lists like `[0, 1]` and `[[0, 1]]` (and `[[0], [1]]`)?  There is a one-one correspondence between list nesting, array dimensions, and [] layering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each element in the main argument of `np.zeros` the function will add a new dimension to the output vector.

Your first code `np.zeros ((1,2))` yields an array with two dimensions, one element in the first dimension and two elements in the second dimension, thus

```
[[0.]
[0.]]
```

The second piece of code has only one element in the main argument, which is translated to "one single dimension, two elements in that dimension". Thus, the output to your `np.zeros((2,))` will be the same as the one for `np.zeros(2)`:

```
array([0., 0.])
```

You could try with a third dimension to see it further:

```
np.zeros((1,2,1))
array([[[0.],
        [0.]]])
```

I short, each square bracket adds to a new dimension based on the elements in the first argument of the function `np.zeros`.

Comment: I am clear about np.zeros((1,2)) but np.zeros((2,)) still bugs me. Can you explain me that?

Comment: Hope it helps now!

Comment: So how can we interpret that? Like, np.zeros((1,2)) means 1 row and 2 columns right? Then, np.zeros((2,)) means what ?

Comment: np.zeros((2,)) means just 2 colunms

Comment: And in fact, `np.zeros((1,2))` means 1 column and 2 rows.

Comment: np.zeros((1,2)) means 1 ROW and 2 COLUMNS. You can test this with matrix multiplication. a = np.zeros((1,3)) b = np.zeros((3,4)), and you'll see np.dot(a,b) will work, but not np.dot(b,a)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I think about it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30900142) helpfully points out that "rows" and "columns" aren't exact parallels for NumPy arrays, which can have n dimensions. Rather, each dimension, or axis, is represented by a number (the size, how many members it has) and in notation by an additional pair of square brackets.

So a 1-dimensional array of size 5 isn't a row or a column, just a 1-dimensional array. When you initialise `np.zeros ((1,2))` your first dimension has size 1, and your second size 2, so you get a 1 x 2 matrix with two pairs of brackets. When you call `np.zeros((2,))` it's just one dimension of size two, so you get `array([0., 0.])`. I also find this confusing - hope it makes sense!

Comment: Simple and easy answer. But https://stackoverflow.com/users/9670056/ibarrond explain me this! So, both of them are correct I guess. Thanks though. Mate!

Answer (score 0):

In the first, the items would be indexed as `[0][0]` and `[0][1]`, and in the second, the items would be indexed by `[0]` and `[1]`.

A shape of `(1,2)` means two dimensions, where the first dimensions happens to have only one index, i.e. it's a matrix with one row.

Comment: Not quite clear. Can you please elaborate? In which case we use either of them?